# Unknown email field with custom user

Tags: django

I am trying to create a custom user by following this [tutorial](https://www.codingforentrepreneurs.com/blog/how-to-create-a-custom-django-user-model/). After starting a new project, I add in the below code and run `python manage.py makemigrations` and receive the following error:

```
File "/Users/me/Desktop/cbv_users/accounts/admin.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .forms import UserAdminCreationForm, UserAdminChangeForm
  File "/Users/me/Desktop/cbv_users/accounts/forms.py", line 32, in <module>
    class UserAdminCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
  File "/miniconda3/envs/server/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 262, in __new__
    raise FieldError(message)
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (email) specified for User
```

Im very confused where this error is coming from and what I am doing wrong. Any help is greatly appreciated. (note: I already set `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.User'` in settings.py) Also, I am using Django 1.11.

**models.py**

```
# accounts.models.py

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import (
    BaseUserManager, AbstractBaseUser
)



class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='email address',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
    )
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    staff = models.BooleanField(default=False) # a admin user; non super-user
    admin = models.BooleanField(default=False) # a superuser
    # notice the absence of a "Password field", that's built in.

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = [] # Email & Password are required by default.

    def get_full_name(self):
        # The user is identified by their email address
        return self.email

    def get_short_name(self):
        # The user is identified by their email address
        return self.email

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        "Does the user have a specific permission?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        "Does the user have permissions to view the app `app_label`?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        "Is the user a member of staff?"
        return self.staff

    @property
    def is_admin(self):
        "Is the user a admin member?"
        return self.admin

    @property
    def is_active(self):
        "Is the user active?"
        return self.active

# accounts.models.py

class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password=None):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given email and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')

        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_staffuser(self, email, password):
        """
        Creates and saves a staff user with the given email and password.
        """
        user = self.create_user(
            email,
            password=password,
        )
        user.staff = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password):
        """
        Creates and saves a superuser with the given email and password.
        """
        user = self.create_user(
            email,
            password=password,
        )
        user.staff = True
        user.admin = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

# hook in the New Manager to our Model
class User(AbstractBaseUser): # from step 2
    objects = UserManager()
```

**forms.py**

```
# accounts.forms.py
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import ReadOnlyPasswordHashField

from .models import User


class RegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Confirm password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email',)

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        qs = User.objects.filter(email=email)
        if qs.exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError("email is taken")
        return email

    def clean_password2(self):
        # Check that the two password entries match
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords don't match")
        return password2


class UserAdminCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """A form for creating new users. Includes all the required
    fields, plus a repeated password."""
    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Password confirmation', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email',)

    def clean_password2(self):
        # Check that the two password entries match
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords don't match")
        return password2

    def save(self, commit=True):
        # Save the provided password in hashed format
        user = super(UserAdminCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user


class UserAdminChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """A form for updating users. Includes all the fields on
    the user, but replaces the password field with admin's
    password hash display field.
    """
    password = ReadOnlyPasswordHashField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'password', 'active', 'admin')

    def clean_password(self):
        # Regardless of what the user provides, return the initial value.
        # This is done here, rather than on the field, because the
        # field does not have access to the initial value
        return self.initial["password"]
```

**admin.py**

```
# accounts.admin.py

from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin


from .forms import UserAdminCreationForm, UserAdminChangeForm
from .models import User

class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    # The forms to add and change user instances
    form = UserAdminChangeForm
    add_form = UserAdminCreationForm

    # The fields to be used in displaying the User model.
    # These override the definitions on the base UserAdmin
    # that reference specific fields on auth.User.
    list_display = ('email', 'admin')
    list_filter = ('admin',)
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('email', 'password')}),
        ('Personal info', {'fields': ()}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields': ('admin',)}),
    )
    # add_fieldsets is not a standard ModelAdmin attribute. UserAdmin
    # overrides get_fieldsets to use this attribute when creating a user.
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('email', 'password1', 'password2')}
        ),
    )
    search_fields = ('email',)
    ordering = ('email',)
    filter_horizontal = ()


admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

Comment: Your `models.py` seems to contain two `User` classes. One has an `email` field, the other does not. Did you mean to specify two classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that you've defined a `User` class twice inside `models.py` and the second definition (which does not contain an `email` field) will shadow the first.

Try removing the second class and then add the custom `UserManager` to the first class.

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    objects = UserManager()  # Add UserManager to first User class

    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='email address',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
    )
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    staff = models.BooleanField(default=False) # a admin user; non super-user        
    admin = models.BooleanField(default=False) # a superuser
    ...


# hook in the New Manager to our Model
class User(AbstractBaseUser): # from step 2    <---- Delete this
    objects = UserManager()
```

You'll need to move the `UserManager` class above the `User` class in `models.py`.

Comment: Cannot believe I didn't catch that before! Thank you!